# RMySQL dbGetQuery() inside function leaves pending results

Tags: r, rmysql

My function, contained in a larger function, uses `dbConnect()`, `dbGetQuery()`, and `dbDisconnect()`.

When the function errors out, I fix it and try to rerun it.  I can't rerun it though, because I get:
 `Error in mysqlCloseConnection(conn, ...) : 
  connection has pending rows (close open results set first)`

(Note 1: I'm not using `dbSendQuery()` + `fetch()`, just `dbGetQuery()`, so this is itself a strange error.)
(Note 2: The errors do NOT occur in the `RMySQL` code; they occur in other parts of the R code.)

Failed solution 1: `dbClearResult(dbListResults(myconnection)[[1]])` does not work because `myconnection` was created inside the function environment.

Failed solution 2: `lapply( dbListConnections( dbDriver( drv = "MySQL")), dbDisconnect)` errors out with the same 'pending rows' error message above.

My only solution now is to kill R and start over.  However, I know that the connection still exists in the SQL database (because my boss tells me such), so I'm seeking a proper solution to close the result/connection.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you tried a combination of failed solution 1 and 2, i.e.: `lapply( dbListConnections( dbDriver( drv = "MySQL")), function(con) dbClearResult(dbListResults(con)[[1]]))`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem so it might help other people in the future...

```
pull<- dbSendQuery(con, statement...)
df2 <- fetch(pull, n = -1)
> dbHasCompleted(pull)
[1] TRUE
> dbDisconnect(con)
[1] TRUE
```